# Is it possible to run a MonetDB cluster on Windows?

Tags: monetdb

It appears that monetdbd is used on Linux based installations to create a multi-node MonetDB cluster. However, monetdbd is not available for Windows. Is there a way to create a MonetDB cluster on multiple Windows hosts without using monetdbd?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. At the moment there is no daemon available for a windows cluster and also not foreseen in the upcoming releases.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to run multiple MonetDB on Windows, you can, but you'll need to manage them yourself.